# How to resolve an undefined value when returning Json result format?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a search filter, each time I insert data type an int, it throws an error to below line and need some help, as to how to resolve it.

When I step into the method Json GetStringData where error is thrown, I saw the 'SearchValue' is undefined.

How does this become possible? How can I change this in order for this code to work? As in where the error is thrown, the data does come back from record, the issue is when search filter is inserted.

ASP.Net

```
     //GET: SearchPeople-ID.
    
            public ActionResult SearchPeopleDetails()
            {
                
                RegCoursesViewModel regCoursesView = new RegCoursesViewModel();
                
                return View(cb.RegPeopleLists.ToList());
            }
    
            // GET://Passing-Data-Back as Json.
            public JsonResult GetSearchingData(string SearchBy, string SearchValue)
            {
                List<eNtsaRegPeopleLists> regPeopleLists = new List<eNtsaRegPeopleLists>();
                if(SearchBy == "ID")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(SearchValue); // Incorrect string format
                        regPeopleLists = cb.RegPeopleLists.Where(v => v.LoginID == Id || SearchValue == null).ToList();
                    }catch(FormatException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} Is Not A ID ", SearchValue);
                    }return Json(regPeopleLists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    regPeopleLists = cb.RegPeopleLists.Where(v => v.Name.StartsWith(SearchValue) || SearchValue == null).ToList();
                    return Json(regPeopleLists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                
            }
     public class eNtsaRegPeopleLists
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [Key]
            public int LoginID { get; set; }
            public string SISID { get; set; }
            public string Role { get; set; }
            public DateTime LastActivity { get; set; }
            public decimal TotalActivity { get; set; }
        }
```

Javascript

```
    <!--Javascript functionality for filter search-->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#SearchLv").keyup(function () {
                var SearchBy = $("#SearchBy").val();
                var SearchValue = $("#Search").val();
                var SetData = $("#DataSearching");
                SetData.html("");
                debugger;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/Home/GetSearchingData?SearchBy=" + SearchBy + "&SearchValue=" + SearchValue,
                    contentType: "html",
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.length == 0) {
                            SetData.append('<tr style="color:red"><td colspan="3">No Match Data</td></tr>')
                        }
                        else {
                            $.each(result, function (index, value) {
                                var Data = "<tr>" +
                                    "<td>" + value.LoginID + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + value.Name + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + value.Role + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + value.SIS_ID + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + value.LastActivity + "</td">  +
                                    "<td>" + value.TotalActivity + "</td>"
                                    "</tr>";
                                SetData.append(Data);
    
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<eNtsaRegistrationTraining.Models.eNtsaRegPeopleLists>

<br />
<br />
<div class="form-group row float-right">
    <form class="form-group ml-lg-auto">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <input class="form-control form-control-navbar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id="SearchLv">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<!--Select-ID-->
<select id="SearchBy">
    <option value="ID">LoginID</option>
    <option value="Name">Name</option>
    <option value="Roles">Roles</option>

</select>
<br />
<br />
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>LoginID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Roles</th>
            <th>SISID</th>
            <th>LastActivity</th>
            <th>TotalActivity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!--Tbody here-->
    <tbody id="DataSearching">
        @foreach(var Item in Model)
        {
           <tr>
              <td>@Item.LoginID</td>
               <td>@Item.Name</td>
               <td>@Item.Role</td>
               <td>@Item.SISID</td>
               <td>@Item.LastActivity</td>
               <td>@Item.TotalActivity</td>
           </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @freedom i have included the HTML code, thanks.

Comment: @freedom i did changed it, the issue, i know its searching my ID, as Int. so if i insert string as a searchValue, it throws that exception. What can  i do?

Comment: It only accepts int, as first value for looking at ID from the record.

Answer (score 0):

search input id is {SearchLv} in your view.

```
<input class="form-control form-control-navbar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id="SearchLv">
```

Either change the id in view

```
<input class="form-control form-control-navbar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id="Search">
```

Or you can change on javascript

```
var SearchValue = $("#SearchLv").val();
```

Comment: @Hamid, if i am inserting as a search by ID only it does not return the value back, as a search filter, client side does return value back. the issue on the controller inside GetStringData method, it only allow search by Int not by string.